# What is the English word for something hidden for a long time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for English word for something that has been hidden for a long time and was difficult to find and finally found.

Something that really took a time and strength to come to the surface.

*A word that is applicable to person, thing or any living or non-living material.*

Comment: Like a family secret  or an hidden truth ?

Comment: Like a treasure that took centuries to locate and unearth?

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean something that was actively hidden, such as jewelry in a house, or something which has simply not been revealed or discovered yet, such as a cave in a remote mountain range (the new Dead Sea Scrolls location comes to mind) or the location of the main wreckage of flight MH370.  That makes a difference.

Comment: Well, as I have mention, it can be thing, person or any other material. Also, I have mentioned that it **took** a time and strength. So, in general, something hidden for a long time (active or inactive), but found.

Comment: "trove" -------

Comment: That *trove* is considered a noun is distinctly regrettable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One expression is ***Holy Grail.*** Sense 2 below, which fits your requirement, is derived from sense 1.

> 1. (in medieval legend) the cup or platter used by Christ at the Last Supper, and in which Joseph of Arimathea received Christ's blood at the Cross. Quests for it undertaken by medieval knights are described in versions of the Arthurian legends written from the early 13th century onward.
> 2. A thing which is eagerly pursued or sought after:
>      *‘the enterprise society where profit at any cost has become the holy grail’*
>
> [[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grail)]

Admittedly, the Grail of legend has never actually been found, but the metaphor — of something precious being long sought — persists.

Comment: I've heard it used by scientists to refer to something long sought for, for example a stable room temperature superconductor.

Answer (score 1):

**Buried** perhaps?

Among other definitions includes:

- to consign to obscurity
- to cover up to hide from sight or knowledge
- [Cover (someone or something) completely](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bury)

Buried also would imply that one would have to put forth effort, by uncovering it to rediscover it.  Just add an additional adjective if you want to emphasize how well hidden it is.  eg: "deeply buried", "well buried", etc.

You might use it like so: "The once deeply buried microwave was recovered just hours ago after teams of firefighters and emergency servicemen gave their lives to bring it to the surface."

Comment: It does not carry a time specificity, though.

Comment: @Hank Unfortunately I don't know of any English word that would cover a time specificity without adding additional modifiers around the phrase.  eg: "the deeply buried treasure took a lengthy amount of time to uncover".

Answer (score 1):

To suss out.

to inspect or investigate (something) in order to gain more knowledge, e.g.: He carefully sussed out the situation.

Comment: However, the word doesn't imply that the sought-after item/info was hidden for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a word that fits the description, and I have been trying to find the correct spelling.  It is shushing or sushing, or something that sounds like those with a different spelling.  If you wanted to know a particular fact about someone during the Revolutionary period, and you had to wade through books and letters and other documents to find it, that is shushing out.  I just don't know how to spell the word and I can't track down that meaning for shushing.n.

It is also used to describe finding out information about a person who has been trying to hide that information, such as an actor who denies he is gay because he thinks it would hurt his career if it became widely known.  But a really good reporter might shush out the truth. I have heard it many times, but never saw it in print.   I have never heard it used about an object.  You might shush out the location of a treasure, but not the treasure itself. 
        Perhaps it is a local colloquialism. I live in Michigan.  I don't know the location of the person who asked for the word.

Comment: See DFW's answer.